# Как вывести Клиента и его полное имя в DataGridView вместо цифр?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Нужно вывести вместо `Client_ID` (= 2) имя, соответствующее этому `Client_ID` в другой таблице. Связь между таблицами показана на скриншотах. Также есть скриншот результата работы программы.

Как это реализовать?

Код вывода в `DataGridView` (работает не так, как я хотел бы):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(int x)
    {
        string status;
        InitializeComponent();
        switch (x)
        {
            case 1: status = "Вы зашли как: Администратор";
                label1.Text = status;
                break;
            case 2: status = "Вы зашли как: Мастер";
                label1.Text = status;
                break;
            case 3: status = "Вы зашли как: Менеджер";
                label1.Text = status;
                break;
            }
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DB database = new DB();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `queryautoservice` ORDER BY  `ID` ", database.getCon());
            database.openCon();
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                data.Add(new string[7]);

                data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][1] = reader[1].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][2] = reader[2].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][3] = reader[3].ToString();

                data[data.Count - 1][4] = reader[4].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][5] = reader[5].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][6] = reader[6].ToString();
            }

            reader.Close();
            database.closeCon();
            foreach (string[] s in data)
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Результат работы программы - выводит цифры а не имена:

[image: Результат работы программы]

Связи между таблицами:

[image: Связи между таблицами]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения ФИО клиента вам требуется присоединить таблицу `clients` к `queryautoservice` (оператор `INNER JOIN`).
В `SELECT` укажите требуемые поля, в данном примере будут получены все значения таблицы `queryautoservice` и `Name`, `SurName`, `Patronymic` таблицы `clients`:

```
string query =
    "SELECT qas.*, clients.Name, clients.SurName, clients.Patronymic " +
    "FROM queryautoservice AS qas " +
    "INNER JOIN clients ON qas.Clients_Id = clients.ID ";

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, database.getCon());
```

Обращаясь к `reader` вы можете получать значения по имени колонки:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var row = new string[7];

    row[0] = reader["Id"].ToString();
    row[1] = reader["DateVisit"].ToString();
    row[2] = reader["Dome"].ToString();
    row[3] = reader["DateReady"].ToString();
    row[4] = reader["Services_ID"].ToString();
    row[5] = $"{reader["Name"]} {reader["SurName"]} {reader["Patronymic"]}";
    row[6] = reader["Masters_ID"].ToString();

    data.Add(row);
}
```

Если вам так же потребуется указать имя вместо `Masters_Id` или `Services_Id` добавьте `INNER JOIN` к ним. Пример:

```
string query =
    "SELECT qas.*, clients.Name AS clietsName, clients.SurName, clients.Patronymic, masters.Name AS masterName, services.Name AS servicesName  " +
    "FROM queryautoservice as qas " +
    "INNER JOIN clients ON qas.Clients_Id = clients.ID " +
    "INNER JOIN masters ON qas.Masters_Id = masters.ID " +
    "INNER JOIN services ON qas.Services_Id = services.ID ";
```

Обратите внимание, что имена колонок должны быть уникальными. Если вам требуется получить столбцы с одинаковым именем из разных таблиц, измените имя столбца оператором `AS`, и после получайте его из `reader` по новому имени.

Comment: Почему он выводит цифры, ничего не поменялось. Может что-то я не так пишу в синтаксис SQL? 
Вот код 
`string query =
               "SELECT * " +
                "FROM queryautoservice " +
                "INNER JOIN clients ON queryautoservice.Clients_ID = clients.ID " +
                "INNER JOIN masters ON queryautoservice.Masters_ID = masters.ID " +
                "INNER JOIN services ON queryautoservice.Services_ID = services.ID ";`

Comment: @Олег  скорее всего в `reader` вы получаете значения по индексу. Тк у вас в запросе select * то сначала идут поля таблицы queryautoservice, потом client  masters, services. Тоесть вам надо посчитать какие столбцы вы хотите вывести. Или обращаться к ним по имени. Советую по имени тк не думаю что вам будет удобно выводить столбец по номеру. Посмотрите как в Select я вывел имя клиента и попробуйте также и с другими таблицами.

Comment: Спасибо, в итоге  `reader` не стал использовать сделал через `adapter` и его метод Fill с помощью которого заполнял datagridview